# FileNotFoundError while importing a csv file using pandas in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

[image: Screenshot of the described error.]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/home/josepm/Documents/test_ver2.csv')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5cd7fd573fb7> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv('/home/josepm/Documents/test_ver2.csv')
```

I try to import a CSV file using pandas and every time it says that it doesn't find the file. It's like Jupyter doesn't see it. I tried to do this:

```
import os
os.path.isfile('/home/josepm/Documents/test_ver2.csv')
```

and it doesn't see the file either.

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: Well the error is self explanatory... you have to find out the right pathe to the file..

Comment: I copied the path from the file properties option panel. It should be this one. How can I find the correct one? Screenshot of the file: [link](https://imgur.com/a/xI6Ov)

Comment: are u connected to a remote notebook by any chance?

Comment: I'm using the browser version of Jupyter. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Try the whole path: `"C:/home/etc/file.csv"` if the file is not in the same folder as notebook, if it is then `"file.csv"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
pd.read_csv('\Users\user\Desktop\Workbook1.csv')
```

to

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Workbook1.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
import os  
path = os.path.abspath(r'file path')
f = open(path)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The working directory is the point from where all the files are accessed in Jupyter Notebook.
>
> Find the current working directory
>
> **import os**
>
> **os.getcwd()**
>
> Example o/p : 'C:\Users\xyz'
>
> Now place your CSV files in this path
>
> List the contents of your directory to check if the CSV file is present
>
> **os.listdir('C:\Users\xyz')**
>
> Now try reading the CSV file

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file directory, then paste it here:

```
pd.read_csv(r'(here)\(csv file name including .csv)').
```

for example:

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\DCL\ML and related\Bengaluru_House_Data.csv')
```

Hope this will work.