# Unknown error in Pycharm Matplotlib from Excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have data in Excel in the form of

Creator, week 1, week2, week3, week4, week5 being the header.

In creator column i have names of the ticket creator and in the week column, i have the number of Tickets created.

Hence i go with the code to plot the graph in pycharm:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('Desktop/creator.xlsx', 'Sheet1')

data1 = data.groupby('Creator').mean().plot(kind = 'bar')

plt.plot(data1)
plt.show(data1)
```

I end up with an error:

- "C:\Users\a294199\gta5\Scripts\python.exe
  C:/Users/a294199/PycharmProjects/gta5/tanker.py Traceback (most
  recent call last):   File
  "C:/Users/a294199/PycharmProjects/gta5/tanker.py", line 5, in

     data = pd.read_excel('Desktop/creator.xlsx')   File "C:\Users\a294199\gta5\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py",
  line 178, in wrapper
     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\a294199\gta5\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py",
  line 178, in wrapper
     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\a294199\gta5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line
  307, in read_excel
     io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)   File "C:\Users\a294199\gta5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line
  394, in **init**
     self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)   File "C:\Users\a294199\gta5\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 111,
  in open_workbook
     with open(filename, "rb") as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desktop/creator.xlsx'

  Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: is the data loaded? i mean is the file getting read? I dont think so, i think the path is incorrect, check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643768/filenotfounderror-while-importing-a-csv-file-using-pandas-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Hello, not sure in pycharm. The file location and the path given is correct. The above code runs perfect in juypter notebook and prints the values and the graph accurately. Not sure what's happening in this.

Comment: I got the data into my file, had to place the file in C drive and then import it. Really strange. Thanks for the help.